# how to make html not read '<' and '>'

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

I'm adding , as innerHTML via javascript in label and it is just not showing any thing at all.
im retriving data from API 's responce

```
{
    "answer_a": "<footer>",
    "answer_b": "<section>",
    "answer_c": "<bottom>",
    "answer_d": "<down>",
    "answer_e": null,
    "answer_f": null
}
```

output it is giving rn is
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oONb0.png)
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmocY.png)

i was expecting this as image
 [an image of expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqgmW.png)

Comment: You need to escape HTML entities.

Comment: Use `innerText` or `textContent`

Comment: there are several ways to read your question so it would be better if you just include what did you try with js to see what did you actually expect to do

Answer (score 0):

When using `.innerHTML` your values are considered html elements.
To prevent this use the property `.text`.